# Best way to copy files from iPhone 13 to Windows computer - (cloudbackup available)

Tags: iphone, itunes, windows, backup, photos

When plugging my mobile phone via USB onto my Windows computer I can copy & paste my whole image folder. But for 100 GB worth of pictures and images I collected in the last 5 years this will not work smoothly. Many crashes, so I started copying folder by folder which is a pain in the ass as well.

Through iTunes I didn't see a possible solution to copy my images locally.

**Is there a reliable way to get all my images to my computer?**

I tought of downloading all through the cloudbackup or something. But so far I didn't find a way.

Since the path to the iPhone is no real path but more a link "This PC\Apple iPhone\Internal Storage\DCIM" I can't use robocopy or other command line tools for a resilient copy job.

Any better ideas?

Comment: iTunes gives the option of syncing the photos on your iOS device to the c:\Users\[username]\Pictures (or other) folder when it is plugged into the PC. Does that not work?

Comment: nope, it is not listing my device, as written in the documentation. Even though I allow "trust device" on my iPhone.

Comment: nope, it is not listing my device in iTunes, I installed iCloud on windows and on the path you mentioned I do have 4.000 pics out of 12.000. (I had icloud installed before once, must have synced at that time. Currently wasn't able to sync the rest.) I do have full sync enabled in photos on my device, so all should be in the cloud.

Comment: Odd, but it has nothing to do with iCloud, it's just a local sync, like it does with music, movies, etc.

Comment: Now I got a popup, your photos from cloud are now in "C:\Users\Computername\Pictures\iCloud Photos\Photos" and there they are :D - but with a cloud Icon, so the thumbnail is downloaded. size on disc is 0kb :-) need to check how to download them fast - could rightclick the folder an select "always keep on this device" this should do it :) - yep it's downloading